# What's "hawk dubious" supposed to mean?

Tags: word-usage

While reading a programming book, I've come across this piece of text:

> Public message boards like Yahoo! Groups and Usenet have long been victims of postings that are unrelated to the board’s subject or that **hawk dubious** products.

Not being a native English speaker, I don't quite get the meaning of this idiom.

How can it be interpreted?

Comment: dubious goes with products-  hawking products that are dubious.

Comment: [hawk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hawk#Verb_2) [dubious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dubious#Adjective).

Comment: _hawk_ means _to sell_.

Comment: "Hawk" tends to imply selling by standing and shouting, as a hot dog vendor at a ballpark.  Though the term may be used figuratively to imply that the seller is using obnoxious advertising, etc.  "Dubious", of course, is an adjective being applied to "products", meaning that the products are of questionable value.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive reply, @HotLicks. I've got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Barmer says, **to hawk** means **to sell**. It's fairly old-fashioned now, or else used in a derogatory way as in your sentence. Respectable residents of a neighbourhood would hang signs on their gates to discourage unwanted callers.

[image]  [image]